# How to make a multidimensional class?

Tags: c++

I've looked at this code from another SO question:

```
template<size_t dimcount, typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector
{
    typedef std::vector< typename multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1, T>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
struct multidimensional_vector<0,T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

multidimensional_vector<1, int>::type v;
multidimensional_vector<2, int>::type v2;
multidimensional_vector<3, int>::type v3;
multidimensional_vector<4, int>::type v4;
```

I was wondering if you could do the same thing as here, but with a class.

```
template<typename T, size_t dim>
class matrix {
    typedef std::vector< matrix<T, dim - 1>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
class matrix<0,T> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

However, the above doesn't seem to work. My goal is to create a N-dimensional matrix.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If you are getting error messages, post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how templating works, and going off your "it doesn't work" i think you have a simple problem:

```
template<typename T, size_t dim>
class matrix {
    typedef std::vector< matrix<T, dim - 1>::type > type;
};

template<typename T>
class matrix<T, 0> {  // NOTICE THIS LINE HERE IS DIFFERENT
    typedef T type;
};
```

This should work, your code before wouldn't because the recursive templating would never hit a base case in `class matrix<0, T>`

Note: now you would declare a matrix like this:

```
matrix<int, 2>::type myMatrix; // expands to std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```